# How does Apache interpret multiple SSLRandomSeed sources

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, mod-ssl, entropy-pool

In my Apache configuration I have these lines:

```
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/random
SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 1024
```

How, exactly, does Apache interpret this? Does it first try builtin and then move to `/dev/random` if that fails? If it uses `/dev/random`, and `/dev/random` then runs out of entropy, does it automatically switch to `/dev/urandom`? Is there an Apache document somewhere that explains all this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not stated in Apache docs, but looking at `ssl_engine_rand.c` (apache 2.2.21 here) you can see that the function `ssl_rand_seed` iterates over all the defined SSLRandomSeed sources, ultimately calling the OpenSSL `RAND_seed` function unless there is a failure.

Refering to the OpenSSL man page for `RAND_seed`, every successful call to it will add entropy to the state of the PRNG.

At the end, it asks OpenSSL if seeding is sufficient trough `RAND_status`.

So, if you define many sources, it will use all of these that work, and combine their entropy.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to file `ssl_engine_rand.c`; it does indeed show that all supplied methods are used and combined.